# Why do PyTorch and Numpy's range indexing allow you to silently index out of bounds?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, pytorch

I stumbled across a strange phenomenon today when debugging some PyTorch code:

I created a tensor like this

```
import torch
mat = torch.rand(3,5)
```

and then indexed it using a range like:

```
print(mat[2,4:7])
```

Lo and behold, it returned the element at `mat[2,4]` alone!, i.e. `mat[2,4:6] == mat[2,4]`. There was no indication that my range extended beyond the bounds of the tensor. However, running:

```
print(mat[2,5])
```

raised the expected `IndexError`: `*** IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for dimension 1 with size 5`

Thinking I had stumbled across a PyTorch bug perhaps, I tested it on `numpy` arrays as well and found the same behavior to hold:

```
import numpy as np
mat = np.random.rand(3,5)
print(mat[2,4:7]) # prints mat[2,4]
print(mat[2,5]) # raises IndexError (*** IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 5)
```

I would have expected this range indexing to at the very least raise a warning or perhaps even to loop around modulo the shape of the dimension so that it returns an array of the expected output shape. Frankly, I'm surprised it doesn't raise an `IndexError` altogether.

**Why is the actual behavior to be expected?**

(Note: I imagine it is based on a Numpy convention first)

Comment: Python allows it too

Comment: Oh, well I guess that makes sense why it would exist in numpy and pytorch too

Comment: @roganjosh: It does indeed. I guess this is a duplicate. Thanks for the pointer! I will vote to close as well.